# Ubuntu Crashing, nothing in logs, Cant find dmesg log in crashdump

Tags: kernel, crash, dmesg

We are running an old version of Ubuntu (14) with kernel 3.16.0-30-generic. We are working with a peripheral that only has 32bit drivers, hence the old version (16 is the last 32bit Ubuntu, however we are still on 14).

We started getting random crashes when running - these did not used to happen before and we are using all the same hardware and Linux images we used to. We suspect, given the chip shortages and supply chain issues, that some component on either the PC or the peripheral we use is bad; and are trying to find something to point our finger at.

The crash happens seemingly randomly; and the OS completely dies. Screen goes black (purple/black); and we have to power cycle. Nothing shows up in any logs in /var/log (syslog, kern.log, or dmesg); we just see a black screen and we have to reboot. So my conclusion is that the kernel is crashing.

I went through lots of debugging steps to try and dump the kernel core and was somewhat successful in doing so. What I am looking for most is the live dmesg at the time of the crash, as I hope it will point us to a specific peripheral or driver that causes the crash. But I am not able to find it in any of the kernel dump logs/files.

Below are my settings, as well as the three things Ive tried so far.

**/etc/default/kdump-tools**

```
# kdump-tools configuration
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# USE_KDUMP - controls kdump will be configured
#     0 - kdump kernel will not be loaded
#     1 - kdump kernel will be loaded and kdump is configured
# KDUMP_SYSCTL - controls when a panic occurs, using the sysctl
#     interface.  The contents of this variable should be the
#     "variable=value ..." portion of the 'sysctl -w ' command.
#     If not set, the default value "kernel.panic_on_oops=1" will
#     be used.  Disable this feature by setting KDUMP_SYSCTL=" "
#     Example - also panic on oom:
#         KDUMP_SYSCTL="kernel.panic_on_oops=1 vm.panic_on_oom=1"
#
USE_KDUMP=1
#KDUMP_SYSCTL="kernel.panic_on_oops=1"


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Kdump Kernel:
# KDUMP_KERNEL - A full pathname to a kdump kernel.
# KDUMP_INITRD - A full pathname to the kdump initrd (if used).
#     If these are not set, kdump-config will try to use the current kernel
#     and initrd if it is relocatable.  Otherwise, you will need to specify
#     these manually.
#KDUMP_KERNEL=
#KDUMP_INITRD=


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# vmcore Handling:
# KDUMP_COREDIR - local path to save the vmcore to.
# KDUMP_FAIL_CMD - This variable can be used to cause a reboot or
#     start a shell if saving the vmcore fails.  If not set, "reboot -f"
#     is the default.
#     Example - start a shell if the vmcore copy fails:
#         KDUMP_FAIL_CMD="echo 'makedumpfile FAILED.'; /bin/bash; reboot -f"
KDUMP_COREDIR="/var/crash"
#KDUMP_FAIL_CMD="reboot -f"


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Makedumpfile options:
# DEBUG_KERNEL - a debug version of the running kernel.  If not set,
#     kdump-config will use /usr/lib/debug/vmlinux-$(uname -r) if it is
#     available.  If it is not available, makedumpfile will be limited to
#     dumping all pages in memory.
# MAKEDUMP_ARGS - extra arguments passed to makedumpfile (8).  The default,
#     if unset, is to pass '-c -d 31' telling makedumpfile to use compression
#     and reduce the corefile to in-use kernel pages only.
#DEBUG_KERNEL=
MAKEDUMP_ARGS="-c -d 31 --dump-dmesg /proc/vmcore dmesgfile"


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Kexec/Kdump args
# KDUMP_KEXEC_ARGS - Additional arguments to the kexec command used to load
#     the kdump kernel
#     Example - Use this option on x86 systems with PAE and more than
#     4 gig of memory:
#         KDUMP_KEXEC_ARGS="--elf64-core-headers"
# KDUMP_CMDLINE - The default is to use the contents of /proc/cmdline.
#     Set this variable to override /proc/cmdline.
# KDUMP_CMDLINE_APPEND - Additional arguments to append to the command line
#     for the kdump kernel.  If unset, it defaults to "irqpoll maxcpus=1 nousb"
#KDUMP_KEXEC_ARGS=""
#KDUMP_CMDLINE=""
#KDUMP_CMDLINE_APPEND="irqpoll maxcpus=1 nousb"

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Architecture specific Overrides:
```

**kdump-config show**

```
USE_KDUMP:        1
KDUMP_SYSCTL:     kernel.panic_on_oops=1
KDUMP_COREDIR:    /var/crash
crashkernel addr: 0x18000000
current state:    ready to kdump

kernel link:


kexec command:
  /sbin/kexec -p --command-line="BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic root=UUID=673608e6-1369-49d0-8f4e-6ee7c70a217b ro memmap=128M$256M vmalloc=280M quiet splash vt.handoff=7 irqpoll maxcpus=1 nousb" --initrd=/boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
```

But when I force a crash using: `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

I get the following output in my /var/crash folder:

- (1KB) linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic 3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1-202208090959.crash
  folder whose name is the date
- (3.8GB) vmcore.CurrentDate
- From here I have tried three things.

**First Item I tried**

First, is to try and open the crash file and see if it includes dmesg. In it I find:

```
ProblemType: KernelCrash
Architecture: i386
Date: Tue Aug  9 09:59:44 2022
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 14.04
Package: linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic 3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1
Uname: Linux 3.16.0-30-generic i686
VmCoreDmesg: base64
 H4sICAAAAAAC/1ZtQ29yZURtZXNnAA==
```

This does not have a readout of Dmesg.

**Second Item**

The second thing I tried is to open the VmCore.CurrentDate file in crash, with:

```
sudo crash ./System.map-3.16.0-30-generic ./vmlinux-3.16.0-30-generic ./202208101500/vmcore.20220810150
```

But this throws an error:

```
crash: ./vmlinux-3.16.0-30-generic: no debugging data available
```

I have tried to find debug symbols for this version of the kernel to no avail; I pulled the vmlinux file from the vmlinuz file in my /boot directory and I doubt it has debug symbols. So I hit a dead end here.

**Third Item...**

The other thing I keep reading is that kdump should output a vmcore-dmesg.txt file, but I have not found any such file. This is really all I thinK I want to point me in one direction or another, but it appears to be missing.

Ive exhausted the internet on this subject, and I hope someone can point me in one direction on another to find what is causing these kernel crashes.

Thanks